# is there a way to have set constructor in inheritence

Tags: java, bluej

So i was wondering if there's a way to set a certain thing for the constructor on bluej
like setting the boolean to true without asking for its parameters

```
public SaleItem(String description,
                double weight,
                boolean canBePickedUp,
                double cost)
{

    // initialise instance variables
    super(description,weight,(canBePickedUp = true));
    this.cost = cost;
}
```

Comment: Is there any issue in doing that? It should be fine as long as `super` is the first statement in the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Java don´t allow default values for non specified parameters. You can do the following

```
public SaleItem(String description, double weight, double cost) {

    // initialise instance variables
    super(description,weight,true);
    this.cost = cost;
}
```

and you can do a second constructor with the canBePickedUp parameter.

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to always initialize `canBePickedUp` to `true`, then**

```
 public SaleItem(String description, double weight, 
                                             boolean canBePickedUp, double cost) {
     // initialise instance variables
      super(description,weight,true);
      this.cost = cost;
 }
```

**It should be fine as long as super is the first statement in the constructor.**